Can a local image in a GitHub repository be displayed in a workflow's step summary using markdown?
The GitHub blog post for job Summaries mentions the ability to use markdown for a job's step summary. If you follow the documentation link in the post it states that...

Job summaries support GitHub flavored Markdown, and you can add your Markdown content for a step to the GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY environment file.

This would imply images are supported, but when I try ![alternate text](relative_path) the  alternate text is showed as a working link to the image.
relative_path == "./process/assets/inactive.png"
Is it possible to display an image in a GitHub workflow step summary?
For reference: GitHub Flavored Markdown Spec

what is "relative_path"? where us the image location and which link you do you put there?

Relevant: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/101814

Yes, good point. I had found it and it state's external images worked for them.
